# Will object detection/segmentation improve classification accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning

if i want to do a classification task will the classification score improve if i have bounding box or pixel wise information?

or will a classification network outperform an object detection/Segmentation network in classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The answer is the following: it depends on the case.

For instance, say you train YoloV3 on 10 types of dogs. Then the output of YoloV3 is a bounding box with the corresponding class.

Having two neural networks however, one for detecting dogs(object detection) and the other one for classification(what type of dog) may perhaps yield a better score.

The same goes for semantic/instance segmentation network.

Although there is no recipe for saying which approach works better, I would personally incline to believe that the second step pipeline would yield slightly better results(there observations are based on my experience, since I have implemented both approaches at a point).